# shell script search and replace sting value with date

Tags: linux, shell, date, sed, ksh

### Script abc.ksh should replace value of file xyz.sql as below

Search for string "%s_sitename as of date "+%Y-%b-%e"" where date changed with sysdate everytime we execute abc.ksh

```
s1='%s_sitename%[a-z][0-9]/-'
s2='%s_sitename%'"$(date "+%Y-%b-%e")"
sed -i 's/'"$s1"'/'"$s2"'/g' xyz.sql
```

abc.sql file should be updated every time with sysdate as below

```
"%s_sitename% as of 2016-Jun-22"
```

With current come I am getting wired output as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1='%s_sitename% as of [a-zA-Z0-9-]*'
s2='%s_sitename% as of '"$(date "+%Y-%b-%e")"
sed -i 's/'"$s1"'/'"$s2"'/g' xyz.sql
```

Test:

```
echo "%s_sitename% as of 2005-Apr-02" | sed 's/'"$s1"'/'"$s2"'/g'
```

Output:

```
%s_sitename% as of 2016-Jun-26
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)